# Download Azure SQL Database

Tags: database, azure

I may be nuts but I can't seem to find any way to get the database I deployed to Azure back!  Does anyone know how to do it?  I know about import/export, backup to blob storage, etc.  I just want to download it.  Help!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read the following:

[How to: Import and Export a Database (Windows Azure SQL Database)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh335292.aspx)

Comment: "I know about import/export, backup to blob storage, etc."

Comment: What do you mean by "download it"? You want to download your entire SQL Azure database or do you want to access data within it?

Comment: Once you have backed it up to blob storage you can restore locally using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: @Craig: Precisely. To "download" an entire SQL Azure database, export it to a BACPAC file in Blob Storage, then download the BACPAC file and import into your local SQL server. But the OP says he understands this so I wonder if some important part of the scenario has been omitted from the question above.

Comment: Richard, Craig:  Thanks.  I was hoping for an easier solution.  I also want to do this in code and can't figure out how to use the DacFx APIs to export from Azure SQL db to storage.

Comment: @User...: You might want to read through this article - I think it covers your scenario: http://mooneyblog.mmdbsolutions.com/index.php/2011/01/11/simple-database-backups-with-sql-azure/

Answer (score 0):

Read my reply here...see it helps...http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ssdsgetstarted/thread/c559d270-12e1-4d4a-8c43-a86e00137631/#887e623e-ffc8-4c60-bf5c-8063fbee003c